# Setting AST nodes as transient (effectively removing them from the AST)?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

For many cases, a complete AST - as specified in a grammar spec - is great, since other code can **obtain any syntactic detail**.

Look at this **AST forest**:

[image]

My ANTLR generated parser is meant to **statically analyze a programming language**. Therefore, the tree `variable -> base_variable_with_function_calls -> base_variable ...` would't be of interest.

Solely the fact, that **$d is a compound_variable** would be enough detail.

**Therefore: May I set somehow a ANTLR production rules as transient, so that ANTLR silently parses the grammar rule, but doesn't create intermediate AST nodes?**

Obviously, such a tag could only be applied to productions, which have a single son node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ANTLR 4 does not support this. The generated parse tree will contain every token matched by the grammar, and will contain a `RuleNode` for every rule invoked by the grammar.